# Looking for Google Map API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am looking for Google location API where I can get user's location. I know I can get user location from Geolocation API. But my requirement is little bit different.

For example, I am writing a access control policy which give my client/consumer access to some resource based on my location not based on client's location. I can get client's location by Geolocation API but how my web app can get my location ?

Is there any Google Map API to delegate my location information from google maps to my developed web app ?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Thanks,
Jabed

Comment: pc/android/ios?

Comment: pc, I mean web application (hosted at localhost currently)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one

[Google Map Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation)

P.S or do you really need the source code for a geolocation web based?